# subprocess.run() on all elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of hostnames / IP addresses, and my script takes the each item from the text file and stores them in the `nodes` variable as a list.

I want to ping each host and output the results to a text file. I can do it with a single host, but am having trouble understanding how to iterate through the list.

I have looked at other posts on Stackoverflow, but most of the posts are using the OS module, which has been deprecated.

**My code:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6

import argparse
import subprocess


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Reads a file and pings hosts by line.")
parser.add_argument("filename")

args = parser.parse_args()

# Opens a text file that has the list of IP addresses or hostnames and puts
#them into a list.
with open(args.filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    nodes = [x.strip() for x in lines]

# Opens the ping program
ping = subprocess.run(
    ["ping", "-c 1", nodes[0]],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)

# Captures stdout and puts into a text file.
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(ping.stdout.decode(), file=f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: I can't work out what your question is sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate directly through your list of nodes like so:

```
with open(args.filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    nodes = [x.strip() for x in lines]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for node in nodes:
        # Opens the ping program
        ping = subprocess.run(
            ["ping", "-c 1", node],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        # Captures stdout and puts into a text file.
        print(ping.stdout.decode(), file=f)
```

Note that you can also directly iterate over your input file, which is said to be more 'Pythonic' than using `readlines()`:

```
with open(args.filename,'r') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        node = line.strip()
        # Opens the ping program
        ping = subprocess.run(
            ["ping", "-c 1", node],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
    # Captures stdout and puts into a text file.
    print(ping.stdout.decode(), file=outfile)
```

Note that this is untested, but I can't see any obvious errors.

Comment: Thank you for help SiHa, I appreciate your help on this! My python script works like I want to with your help.

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate through the nodes list like this:

```
for i in nodes:   
    ping = subprocess.run(
    ["ping", "-c 1", i],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Hope it helps :)